# Air Gesture Javascript Events For Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch, gesture

I am developing a mobile web pages targeting for samsung galaxy S4. There i want to use the air gesture events. Could anyone please explain how to capture the air gesture events using javascript. Is there any event present for air gesture, like normal touch events touchstart, touchend? Thanks in advace.

Comment: AirMotion is only for Native Android , no Javascript. And it doesn't support S4. You can find my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649830/proximity-sensor-on-galaxy-s4-air-gestures/21853837#21853837