# Proximity sensor on Galaxy S4 (Air Gestures)

Tags: android, gesture, android-sensors, galaxy, samsung-mobile-sdk

The new Samsung Galaxy S4 have and interesting new type of gestures called "*Air Gesture*" that use an infrared sensor to process users hand movement in front of the screen, adding a "*pre-touch*"/"*proximity*" event, in which the fingers are detected before the touch.

I'd like to use this "*Floating Touch*" event in one of my apps. I searched both on Google and in the Samsung Developers Center, but I couldn't find any API or information about that.

Are the API available or is too early? Does someone have any link/info?

http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxys4/lifetask.html#page=airview

[image: Air Gestures]

Comment: I think those gestures are controlled by front camera.

Comment: I dunno Samsung says that it uses special screen technology... anyway, is there an API to get the "Floating Touch" event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a good [youtube video from a Google I/O session](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0V_ld7iNw4&list=PL4C6BCDE45E05F49E&index=4) called "the sensitive side of Android" that explains how you could do something similar. Basically you use the light sensors and then you register a drop. This is quite simple but you gotta remember that changing light sources while running the app can affect the results of this feature.

That said I think they use hand detection on the front camera in order to pull off all those gestures and that would be quite complex. Also I haven't seen any api that makes it simple to do hand detection.

Comment: Nope, they do not use the camera at all for hand gesture detection in S4. Tested simply by blocking the camera.

Comment: Thanks @Warpzit, do you know where can I get the source code in the I/O demo? I'm really having trouble sampling those data from the sensor:(

Comment: In the samples folders there is a project called Accelerometer Play, API Demos (OS - Sensors). They'd be a good place to start.

Answer (score 4):

Yon can find it what you want

> The Samsung Mobile SDK 1.5 beta1 consists of 16 independent packages;
> including 'Pass' and 'Motion', which allow you to make use of the
> Finger Print and Activity Recognition features of the Samsung GALAXY
> S5.
>
> New: Accessory, Accessory File Transfer, Companion UI Profile, Health, Pass, Remote Sensor
>
> Update: Chord, **Gesture**, Motion(Activity Recognition)
>
> You can import one or more packages into your application as your
> project requires. For more information on the contents of each
> package, please check below.

http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile-sdk#gesture

Comment: Please do not provide "link-only" answers -- especially when an accepted answer has already been provided. Once you've earned a little positive reputation you'll be able to post things like that as a comment, which is acceptable.

Comment: @mah actually user2594675's answer is the correct one for this question.

Comment: @zrgiu Actually, link-only answers are not permitted at stack overflow, so it doesn't matter what the link contains. What is permitted is copying enough of the content from that link into the answer so that the answer can stand alone and be useful even after the link breaks (but including the link for reference, attribution, and additional details is very welcomed).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to Samsung Mobile SDK, you'll find that S4 doesn't support Gesture SDK although it had "floating gesture" function. If you google "Samsung Mobile Gesture SDK with S4", you'll find some info....

Only Galaxy J and Note 3 support Gesture SDK as far as I know.